# What is the proper way to debug an npm script using vscode?

Tags: node.js, npm, visual-studio-code

I've got an npm script that I'm trying to debug. I use vscode so I thought I'd create a debug configuration and step through it with the debugger.

My npm script look is:

```
"scripts": {
    ...
    "dev": "node tasks/runner.js",
}
```

So I created the following debug config:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "run", "dev"
            ],
            "port": 5858,
            "stopOnEntry": true
        }
    ]
}
```

And when I fire it the script runs, but vscode is never able to connect and I get the error:

> Cannot connect to runtime via 'legacy' protocol; consider using 'inspector' protocol (timeout after 10000 ms).

I tried adding an inspector protocol:

```
       {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Attach (Inspector Protocol)",
            "port": 9229,
            "protocol": "inspector"
       }
```

And running the npm script via:

```
npm run dev --inspect
```

And this time I get the error:

> Ensure Node was launched with --inspect. Cannot connect to runtime process, timeout after 10000 ms - (reason: Cannot connect to the target: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9229).

I'm not sure what part I'm missing.

*Edit per duplicate tag*

I see the other question re: debugging an npm script via vscode, but the details in the other question and answers aren't as detailed and specific. If someone is searching for the specific vscode error messages I ran into or the config type I had they wouldn't necessarily get the level answer detail that this question's chosen answer gives.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to debug using npm run scripts from VSCode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34835082/how-to-debug-using-npm-run-scripts-from-vscode)

Comment: Agreed at duplicate, and I recommend this answer on that post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68959015/3144603. VScode has built-in support for debugging npm scripts now.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You shouldn't try to debug the `npm script` because what you really want is to attach your debugger to the script that is launched with npm run command (NPM here is used only as a task runner).

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
      {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Program",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/tasks/runner.js"
      }
  ]
}
```

If you really want to run it using npm script, then you can use the following configuration:

```
{
  "type": "node",
  "request": "launch",
  "name": "Launch via NPM",
  "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
  "windows": {
    "runtimeExecutable": "npm.cmd"
  },
  "runtimeArgs": [
    "run-script",
    "dev"
  ],
  "port": 5858
}
```

but you also have to [change](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_launch-configuration-support-for-npm-and-other-tools) your script command (specify a debug port)

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node --nolazy --debug-brk=5858 tasks/runner.js"
  },
```

You can explore various debug configurations simply by clicking the gear icon and selecting one.

[image]

More about Node.js debugging can be found in the [VS Code documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging).

Comment: DeprecationWarning: `node --debug` and `node --debug-brk` are invalid. Please use `node --inspect` or `node --inspect-brk` instead.  Works with new --inspect-brk in new versions