# Attaching grunt to VSCODE debugger

Tags: javascript, debugging, visual-studio-code

I am trying to attach my default grunt tasks to vscode debugger. So my desired workflow is I start the debugger and it runs the default grunt tasks and then I am able to put breakpoints in my code using vscode debugger. My launch JSON file looks like this.

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt",
            "args": ["run"],
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "preLaunchTask": null,
            "runtimeExecutable": null,
            "runtimeArgs": [
            "--nolazy"
            ],
            "env": {
                "NODE_ENV": "production"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Attach to Process",
            "port": 5858
        }
    ]
}
```

But I am getting an error can't launch program 'node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt'; setting the 'outfiles' attribute might help

Comment: What does your grunt task do? Does it just run the application or there is a compilation step? If it's the first, then there are already many similar questions for task runners, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43210203/what-is-the-proper-way-to-debug-an-npm-script-using-vscode/43212281#43212281. 
If your `run` task also compiles sources then you can define a Node.js debugg configuration with a `preLaunchTask` option set.

Comment: @jsynowiec its the latter, can you direct me on how to achieve this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to debug your compiled code, you have to define the build task in `tasks.json` and then specify it as a `preLaunchTask` in your `launch.json` configuration.

Also remember to augment your build config so it outputs source maps. With source maps, it is possible to single step through or set breakpoints in the original source.

You need to configure the tasks in a `tasks.json` file (located under your workspace `.vscode` folder). If you don't already have a `tasks.json` file, running the **Tasks: Configure Task Runner** action from the Command Palette (<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> on macOS or <kbd>F1</kbd> on Windows/Linux) will offer you a set of templates to pick from. Select `Grunt` from the list and it will generate a file that should look like this:

```
{
  // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
  // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "command": "grunt",
  "isShellCommand": true,
  "args": ["--no-color"],
  "showOutput": "always"
}
```

now you can define your build task:

```
{
  ...
  "showOutput": "always",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "taskName": "build",
      "args": [],
      "isBuildCommand": true
    }
  ]
```

Assuming that your Grunt builds your app from `src/app.js` to `dist`, you can define your launch configuration like this:

```
{
  "type": "node",
  "request": "launch",
  "name": "Launch",
  "program": "${workspaceRoot}/src/app.js",
  "sourceMaps": true,
  "outFiles": ["${workspaceRoot}/dist/**/*.js"],
  "preLaunchTask": "build"
}
```

You can read more in the VS Code documentation - [Node.js Debugging in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_supported-nodelike-runtimes).

Comment: This does not remotely answer the question asked. The question asked is about debugging the build itself, not the result of the build.