# Not able to set up debugger in visual studio code for node applicaiton

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, vscode-debugger

i have a nodejs application and i make it up by grunt serve.

I am trying to debug it using visual studio code

What exactly should i put in launch.json? Any specific command for grunt?
i tried following and got error could not find build task

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}\\server\\server.js",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "outFiles": ["${workspaceRoot}\\dist\\**/*.js"],
            "preLaunchTask": "build"
          }

    ]



}
```

Comment: Did you try go through documentation online for VSCode launch configuration and Grunt? I assume not. In case you tried, but nothing worked, what exactly did you try and what the result was?

Comment: i have uddated the question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Attaching grunt to VSCODE debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43454168/attaching-grunt-to-vscode-debugger)