# VS Code: How can I select predefined launch.json configurations for debugging an NPM task?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, vscode-tasks

How can I debug NPM tasks from `package.json` file in the current version of Visual Studio Code and NPM?

I can only find answers on StackOverflow that seem to provide obsolete strategies.

In [one of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43210203/what-is-the-proper-way-to-debug-an-npm-script-using-vscode) a huge list of configurations is shown:

[image: Current Visual Studio Code launch configurations]

But I can only see a selection of four:

[image: Current Visual Studio Code launch configurations]

I need to debug a mocha test script from a public repository.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select Node.js and then you should see more options.  There's also an "Add Configuration..." button at the bottom right of the editor when the launch.json file is open.

[See this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launch-configurations) for more information.