# Running npm test in a debug terminal in VSCode

Tags: node.js, debugging, npm, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to create a configuration in my launch.json which will run `npm test` in the folder in which the `.js` file resides.  Running `npm test` manually in a terminal works fine, taking the relevant command from the `scripts` part of my `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node --experimental-json-modules nodeserver.js",
    "test": "export MY_VAR=abc && node --experimental-json-modules nodeserver.js"
},
```

In particular, when running `npm test` directly in a terminal, the env var specified in the `test` script line takes effect and the `--experimental-json-modules` flag is passed to `node`.

This is my launch.json:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "command": "npm test",
            "name": "Run npm test",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "node-terminal"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is pretty much as-is from one of the predefined options suggested in the editor, and is very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65768495/4070848).

But when I run this configuration on the `nodeserver.js` file, I get:

[image]

It seems to be running `node` without the flag I specified in the configuration?  What am I misunderstanding about how this `launch.json` scheme works?

EDIT the more I've played around, the more it seems as if the configuration is just being completely ignored, so that it is using the default node.js configuration... I'm selecting the config from the drop-down and pressing the play icon:

[image]

Should that work?

Apart from running `npm start` in a terminal, the only "automatic" way of getting this to work is by opening the `package.json` and clicking on the little Debug button which appears by the `scripts` tag:

[image]

But I'd like to figure out how to use `launch.json` properly so that I can pass environments variables etc via that instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create the npm test script directly in your launch.json as above:

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Run npm test",
        "request": "launch",
        "type": "node",
        "args": ["--experimental-json-modules", "${workspaceFolder}/nodeserver"],
        "env": {
           "MY_VAR": "abc"
        }

    }
]
}
```

Comment: Exactly the same happens with this `launch.json` too...  it seems as if the configuration is just being completely ignored, so that it is using the default node.js launch configuration.

Answer (score 0):

launch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "pwa-node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**"
            ],
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\index.js"
        },
        {
            "type": "pwa-node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Run Test",
            "skipFiles": 
            [
                "<node_internals>/**"
            ],

            // You can specify enviorment variables per config here
            // using key value pairs
            "env": 
            {
                "test_variable": "test value"
            },

            // You can also specify a .env file that contains them
            "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",

            // Here you specify the file you want launched
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\test.js",

            // add args to nodejs here
            "runtimeArgs": 
            [
                "--experimental-json-modules"
            ],
        }
    ]
}
```

For reference:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging

Comment: Exactly the same happens with this `launch.json` too... it seems as if the configuration (including the `--experimental-json-modules` arg) is just being completely ignored, so that it is using the default node.js launch configuration, without any args.  Maybe I'm just launching this incorrectly... how are you doing it?  The way I'm doing it is in the original post.

Comment: @drmrbrewer I select the profile and then press F5. I just gave that switch a test and it worked. https://i.imgur.com/CiRXX6X.png

Comment: Yep. F5 is the equivalent of what I was doing... pressing the "play" button next to the profile name... still I get the same error and the runtime args specified are just being completely ignored... no idea what's going on.